# How do I get wifi working on my laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

I have searched for many hours trying to get the wifi to work on my new Lenovo IdeaPad laptop. I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 installed alongside of Windows 11. I've tried everything I've seen on this website and others, but I had no luck. I even have a USB wifi adapter that it recognizes, but when I switch the drivers for it, nothing happens.

USB wifi adapter driver message:

[image: USB wifi adapter driver message]

`lsusb` shows the wifi adapter:

[image: lsusb shows the wifi adapter]

Comment: Are you asking about the USB device or about a built-in wireless?

Comment: @Pilot6 Honestly whichever one I can get working. I focused on the USB adapter because at least the drivers for it popped up.

Comment: @waltinator I ran the wireless diagnostic. I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to do with that info? Is there certain parts from it that I need to share here to help my problem be solved?

Comment: @Allen You are supposed to post the output to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 Apologies. I tried poosting it here, but stackexchange thinks there's links in the diagnostic text and it says I need a higher reputation to have that many links. Is there another way for me to post it?

Comment: If you format text properly there will be no links. If it is hard for you, you can post the tect to pastebin. Everything is explained it the duplcate link. It seems you didn't read it at all.

Comment: Copy the text from the terminal. You may use your mouse to highlight all the text and right click and choose copy. The directly paste the text [into your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425660/edit). Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.